# What do we know about Long Covid and Omicron?

Tags: covid-19

Longer term covid symptoms/sequalia ("Long covid") tentatively seem to be attributed to the virus playing havoc with bodily organs, the bloodstream, perhaps the immune system, and so on. Its not yet known how its caused, but medically seems to happen.

According to lab and study data, the omicron variant seems to target the airway much more, but less so the deeper lung tissues of Delta and earlier. So in principle we might expect to see milder and much less common presentation of long covid symptoms/sequalia, as well:

- the disease infection phase is more usually described as milder presentation to start with
- the disease does not target deep lung tissues to the same extent as Delta and earlier.

Is there any medical evidence yet, to support or reject this speculation about omicron recovery and aftermath?

Comment: I don't think omicron has existed long enough for there to be much, if any, knowledge of how it behaves with regard to long COVID. I don't think we'll have an answer to this question for another several months.